# How to correctly register specific GCC version in Linux (Debian/Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, debian

If I install `build-essential` in Linux, i will get `gcc` version corresponding to distro version, ex for `Debian 6.0.9` i will get `gcc-4.4`. But some installers (for example, Nvidia installer) requires specific version, for example `gcc-4.3`. The problem is - if I install specific `gcc` version manually, ex:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.3
```

the installed executable name will be `gcc-4.3` and `/usr/bin/gcc` symlink will still point to `gcc` version installed by `build-essential` (which is `gcc-4.4`).

The question is - is it any standard, user-friendly way to "switch" "current" `gcc` version (the `gcc` command), without manually relinking all symlinks from `gcc-4.4` to `gcc-4.3` which is error-prone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way is to use `update-alternatives`. For `gcc` it will be:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.3 60
```

where `60` is a priority.